# How to use solr.DateRangeField in solr-5.3.1-0

Tags: solr

I am stock in this issue for days now.  We are upgrading our system to solr 5.3, after doing some minor change to the old schema everything works fine until we decide to try this new fieldType **solr.DateRangeField**, If we use this field type SOLR no longer work.

See below on how we implement it.  I can't figure this out, need help.

Thank You

```
<field name="appointments" type="rdates" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="rdates" class="solr.DateRangeField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix my issue with help from [solr irc](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#solr)

I just remove the precisionStep and positionIncrementGap attributes in my type declaration then restart solr.  See new type declaration below.

```
<fieldType name="rdates" class="solr.DateRangeField" multiValued="true"/>
```